# How to create iCloud Calendar Events?

Tags: python, python-3.x, calendar, icloud

I just wrote my Calendar app with python for my Uni, but I have one problem, I can't find a way to create or import events to the apple iCloud Calendar. I tried the apple-calendar-integration, but makes an error with the token and pyicloud but it cant create events...
Maybe someone has an idea about that?